# how to merge multiple rows of a google worksheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to combine the resulting rows collected in a form response sheet according to the date of submission (e.g. 29/10/2017) into a single row.
How can I create the result as you can see in row 11 without using concatenate function? The problem is I have thousands of columns and around 40 rows to combine the result. Therefore, if I use concatenate, it will be very inefficient and error-prompt.

Thanks.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erH3Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try `QUERY`

```
=QUERY(B2:N9,,500)
```

By using 500 as header argument, We  essentially CONCATENATE all the columns.